# Task :react-native-screens:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

Im using react navigation v5.. installed all the dependencies.. now Im getting above error..
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-screens:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

Comment: Add your react and react native versions to your question

Comment: "react": "16.9.0",
 "react-native": "0.61.5",

Comment: have same issue

Answer (score 5):

Run this command in your terminal

1. cd android

// to check if there are any deamon running.

2. ./gradlew --status or .\gradlew --status
3. ./gradlew --stop
4. ./gradlew clean
5. cd ..

// then restart the server

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue is still open on GitHub issues -> [View](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/123)

If your React Native Version < 0.60 then you can use Jetifier to solve this issue

[How to use Jetifier to solve ?](https://github.com/mikehardy/jetifier)

1. `yarn add --dev jetify`
2. Then in your package.json scripts add:

   - `"postinstall": "jetify"`
3. yarn jetify

If your React Native Version 0.60 > then try this

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean
```

Comment: @Arun.k try to remove node_modules and reinstalling it. Then run

Comment: you mean should i delete node_modules folder or delete depednencies ?

Comment: Yes delete node_modules folder and install it using npm install

Comment: Tnx for ur response Sir... I resolved this issue by installing alpha dependencies of react navigation(next)

Comment: I do not get this error while running the app from android studio, but get it while running 'react-native run-android'

Comment: @Arun.k Can you please elaborate on which alpha dependencies you have installed? I am facing same issue and tried to install all the dependencies specified in [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/).

Answer (score 1):

it do it when you upgrade your react-native version to 0.69.1 or higher insert the kotlin classpath to build.gradle of app(android\build.gradle) :
dependencies {
.....
classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10") ----- this line
.....
// NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
// in the individual module build.gradle files
}

sorry for my english

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).